# angular ui-router, how to nest states with a url that updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'd like to know how to join three states together when running through a wizard-like setup.
The app I'm currently developing has a "Parameters" screen that asks the user in 3 steps to enter some parameters. These 3 steps should be joined on the same page but the current step should only get visible when that particular step needs to get filled in.

Somewhat like this:

User starts at: `parameters/step-1`

- first div is visible
- second div is hidden (or in a sort of blocked/locked state)
- third div is hidden (or in a sort of blocked/locked state)

User fills in step 1 and navigates to `parameters/step-2`

- first div is visible
- second div is visible
- third div is hidden (or in a sort of blocked/locked state)

User fills in step 2 and navigates to `parameters/step-3`

- first div is visible
- second div is visible
- third div is visible

This is my current setup, is this the correct way of doing this or should I work with nested views and then show/hide each view manually depending on the current route? And if so, how do I do this?

```
.state('test.parameters', {
  url: "/parameters",
  templateUrl: "views/partials/enter-parameters.html"
})
.state('test.parameters.step1', {
  url: "/step-1",
  templateUrl: "views/partials/step1.html"
})
.state('test.parameters.step2', {
  url: "/step-2",
  templateUrl: "views/partials/step2.html"
})
.state('test.parameters.step3', {
  url: "/step-3",
  templateUrl: "views/partials/step3.html"
})
```

Comment: do you have to use seperate views for every step? it looks to me like you'll be better off with just ngShow/ngHide (or ngIf) them

Comment: A good suggestion, I'll give that a try ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article on the ng-newsletter website](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html) describes your exact example. Somebody also commented on the article and added a [Wizard jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwebe0pe/wU62P/). I've adjusted the code from the article to fit your example.

To answer the question here, what you would do is set your test.parameters to an abstract state, which means you cannot refer to it directly, but it does give you the abstract url of test.parameters. Once one of the abstract state's children is navigated to (either by a user or by a part in your script), the url will be updated to the url of the abstract state in combination with the child url (in your case that would be [mainUrl]/parameters/test1). Each of the test.parameters.step[x] states is a child of the abstract state and you switch between them using the sref element in  tags within the templateUrl's that you mentioned. I've left the $urlRouterProvider to show you how to access the first step of you abstract state.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/test.parameters/step1');

$stateProvider
.state('test.parameters', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/parameters',
    templateUrl: "views/partials/enter-parameters.html"
})
.state('test.parameters.step1', {
    url: '/step1',
    templateUrl: "views/partials/step1.html"
})
.state('test.parameters.step2', {
    url: '/step2',
    templateUrl: "views/partials/step2.html"
})
.state('test.parameters.step3', {
    url: '/step3',
    templateUrl: "views/partials/step3.html"
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the "problem" with this approach is that it doesn't join the 3 steps onto 1 page (or view). They get switched. In my case step 2 has to appear underneath step 1 after step 1 gets completed.

Comment: Ah, sorry, overlooked that part. Apart from the tip Pan Stav gave you (did that work for you?), you could also try out the [named views that ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) has. You would add three named views and use an <a> tag with the sref parameter in each step[x].html file to fill each consecutive view. Just a thought :)

Comment: I figured that, in my application, it wasn't a good idea to have deep links to each specific step. So the tip Pan Stav gave was an eye opener. But I'm still interested in the solution to my initial question. My current solution is based on this: http://onehungrymind.com/ng-animate-first-look-with-angularjs-wizard/

Comment: Well, to answer your initial question, I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyEokyZXIeqKyDAJ2ZYE) which shows you how you would make the state changes necessary to get the effect on the website that you linked too. Without the fancy animation and the updating of variables, but those you could add yourself.